# Mysql Master-Master Replication Error

Tags: mysql, replication

Configured Master-Master Replication

But both servers slave shows the below error !!

> Last_IO_Errno: 1236
>
> Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from
> binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index
> file'

How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mysql-replication-got-fatal)

This error occurs when the slave server required binary log for replication no longer exists on the master database server. In one of the scenarios for this, your slave server is stopped for some reason for a few hours/days and when you resume replication on the slave it fails with above error.

When you investigate you will find that the master server is no longer requesting binary logs which the slave server needs to pull in order to synchronize data. Possible reasons for this include the master server expired binary logs via system variable expire_logs_days – or someone manually deleted binary logs from master via PURGE BINARY LOGS command or via ‘rm -f’ command or may be you have some cronjob which archives older binary logs to claim disk space, etc. So, make sure you always have the required binary logs exists on the master server and you can update your procedures to keep binary logs that the slave server requires by monitoring the “Relay_master_log_file” variable from SHOW SLAVE STATUS output. Moreover, if you have set expire_log_days in my.cnf old binlogs expire automatically and are removed. This means when MySQL opens a new binlog file, it checks the older binlogs, and purges any that are older than the value of expire_logs_days (in days). Percona Server added a feature to expire logs based on total number of files used instead of the age of the binlog files. So in that configuration, if you get a spike of traffic, it could cause binlogs to disappear sooner than you expect. For more information check Restricting the number of binlog files.

In order to resolve this problem, the only clean solution I can think of is to re-create the slave server from a master server backup or from other slave in replication topology.